# Dyanamic URLS Caching in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I am basically trying to implement a form on a standard Wordpress page and create dynamic pages based on the form inputs. So the urls generated would be like example.com/form/value. But i am not sure how to do this in Wordpress. Another problem is caching of the generated page. I am using WP Super Cache, is there any way to cache these dyanmic pages and set custom expiry dates?

Comment: You can get the `$_POST` variables and then do a `header()` redirect, based on that `$_POST` value.

Comment: How to get the variable from URL, i mean if i go through form it is okay, but if i try to directly access the url without goin gthrough form, i would get an error right?